# Nvidia driver not loading properly for Geforce GTX 570hd

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, gpu-driver

I'm having a problem with using the nvidia driver for my Geforce GTX 570.

I've tried re-installing the drivers, installing using the `.sh` file from nvidia's website, and using every driver available from the additional drivers program. I have also tried installing using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` and `nvidia-current-updates`.

I will be very grateful if you could help fix this issue, or even give me advice. Thank you in advance.

---

- The driver is selected in additional drivers, but if I run the `sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf` command, it shows it is not in use.

  Using that command, I can change to the nvidia driver, but when I boot after that I am given a black screen that simply says: 'Starting version 219' and does nothing else. From that screen, if I open a `tty` then I can try `sudo service lightdm start` but it fails, and running `startx` also fails. (See following screenshots labeled as 1 and 2 respectively).

I have been on the [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2279938) with this same problem, and have received many replies but we haven't been able to work out a solution over there. So I decided to post here also to see if any of you may know a working solution.

---

*Additional information:*

I am using a DVI cable to connect to my monitor.

- Here is the output of running `lspci`:

  ```
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 [GeForce GTX 570 Rev. 2] (rev a1)
  ```

  Full output is uploaded: [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11504369/)
- This is what I see when I open up Nvidia X Server Settings:

  [image: Nvidia X Server Settings]
- This is the contents of [`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11381825/)
- Here are the screenshots mentioned above:

  Screenshot 1 -

  [image: Screenshot 1]

  Screenshot 2 -

  [image: Screenshot 2]
- Here is the link to my post in [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2279938).

  There you will probably find the answer to any question you might have, but I am more than happy to answer those questions here as well.

Comment: which driver version is installed? If you have installed `nvidia-current` add the output of the command `apt-cache policy nvidia-current`

Comment: Forget my comment, I have read the ubuntuforums thread. Have you tried the PPA `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your kernel (assuming you're on Trusty)? The Vivid Vervet 3.19 kernel is now available in the Trusty repositories, so you might want to try that. It probably won't hurt.

Comment: Forgive me as I am not an advanced linux user, but how can I add the Trusty repositories? Also, after adding, will `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` upgrade to 3.19?

Comment: @MatthewC , could you post output of `apt-cache policy "nvidia-*"` to http://paste.ubuntu.com  (as A.B.  mentions) So we know what's your current state. In addition to that the output of `dkms status`

Comment: Matthew C, if you're not on Trusty I (probably) can't help you. What version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: Also, why do you use NVIDIA's driver anyway? Was the default open-source driver not good enough for you (i.e. OpenGL too old)?

Comment: Did you tried to create a new xorg.conf file? `sudo X -configure; sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`